# cannot import name 'Settings' from partially initialized module 'CatchBall.A.Settings'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, python-import

Python es mi primer lenguaje, soy nuevo, uso el editor de codigo "eclipse" con el plug-in pydev  para python y estaba intentando crear un juego con diferentes modulos que cree a lo que me salen los siguientes errores:

[image: La administracion de archivos(por si es que hay algo mal aqui)]

**A(principal)**

```
import sys
import pygame as pg

from CatchBall.A.Background import Background
from CatchBall.A.Scoreboard import Scoreboard
from CatchBall.A.Ball import Ball
from CatchBall.A.Catch import Catch
from CatchBall.A.Menu import Menu
from CatchBall.A.Settings import Settings
from CatchBall.A.Sounds import Variables
from CatchBall.A.GameFunctions import GameFunctions

pg.init()

#Variables:
s = Settings()
gf = GameFunctions()
bg = Background()
sb = Scoreboard()
```

**Background**

```
#Class for the backgrounds
from CatchBall.A.Settings import Settings

#Variables
s = Settings()
```

**Catch**

```
#Class for the Catch

from pygame.sprite import  Sprite
from CatchBall.A.Settings import Settings

#Variables
s = Settings()
```

**GameFunctions**

```
#Class for the game functions
from CatchBall.A.Settings import Settings
import pygame as pg
import sys

#Variables: 
s = Settings()
```

**Settings**

```
#Class for the settings


import pygame as pg
from CatchBall.A.Catch import Catch
```

Ya busque el mismo error y trate varias soluciones pero no pude lograr que se ejecute.

Comment: Haz intentado importar el módulo sin CatchBall.A?

Comment: Asi es, ahi subi una foto de como estan agrupados los archivos por si es que hay un error que no haya entendido

Comment: En el módulo `Settings` no tienes ningún objeto llamado `Settings` que se pueda importar. En python, los módulos no se corresponden implícitamente con una clase. En python, todo es *explícito*.

Comment: no entiendo, como deberia hacer el import para que no me de el error? ya probe con todas las formas. cree el objeto setting en la clase Settings e igual no me deja importarlo a otro modulo.